# Where did Vivekananda say "Anything against science is not religion?"

Tags: science, vivekananda

In [this interview](https://indianexpress.com/article/india/ks-bhagwan-interview-if-one-follows-constitution-one-can-enrage-some-sections-gauri-lankesh-muirder-5096888/), [K. S. Bhagawan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K._S._Bhagawan) quotes Swami Vivekananda as saying whenever there's a conflict between the two, science takes precedence over religion.

> Why should developing a spirit of inquiry be seen as going against a particular people or religion? It’s not so. Scientific inquiry is essential for everyone. **Swami Vivekananda said nearly 125 years ago, "If there is anything against science, it is not religion. And you should reject it."** He had a great scientific outlook and I look upon him as a spiritual mentor.

Did Vivekananda really say so (or something to that effect)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79357/discussion-on-question-by-sv-did-vivekananda-say-anything-against-science-is-n).

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34352/is-religion-different-from-science-especially-when-it-comes-to-falsifiability . There is no difference between religion and science when it comes to falsifiability. The reason people think it's different is because they are willing to perform the test/verification mentioned by one sect, and unwilling to perform the test/verification mentioned by another sect, hence they ascribe the fault to the sect rather than themselves.